# Преобразовать данные на выходе, python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть некий json:

```
data:
    {
     'value': 'aa','bd','07','0','1a','b5','0','a','1','f6'
    }
```

Необходимо написать код на python, в результате которого запятые изменяться на пробелы, а к одиночным значениям, например, '1' или 'a', впереди добавится 0. В результате должно получится что-то вроде такого:

```
data:
    {
     'value': 'aa' 'bd' '07' '00' '1a' 'b5' '00' '0a' '01' 'f6'
    }
```

Comment: а где запятые поменялись на пробелы ?

Comment: Внес изменения в вопрос

Comment: У вас что до, что после это невалидный JSON.
Может так?
    {
     "value": ["aa", "bd", "07", "00", "1a", "b5", "00", "0a", "01", "f6"]
    }

Comment: Джейсон это строка. Заменить в строке один символ на другой сможет даже третьеклассник. Для второй части задания используй регулярные выражения.

Comment: @Alpensin да, так

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял суть задачи, то должно получиться что-то вот такое:

```py
data =   {'value': ['aa','bd','07','0','1a','b5','0','a','1','f6'] } 
data['value'] = ' '.join(map(lambda x: x.zfill(2), data.get('value')))
print(data)
# {'value': 'aa bd 07 00 1a b5 00 0a 01 f6'}
```